Prove multiplication of Dedekind cuts is associative.
I'm trying to prove that multiplication of Dedekind cuts is associative. I've read some proof online, but they all have a step I feel uncomfortable with. They say that a rational $q$ is in their product $(\alpha\beta)\gamma$ if $q\le abc$ for some $0 < a \in \alpha$, $0 < b \in \beta$, and $0 < c \in \gamma$ right away, a step I don't understand and something that doesn't seem to follow directly from the definition. Can anyone help?

There are a few different definitions of product of Dedekind cuts, all equivalent,  so it would help to know from which definition you are starting.
